# Linking C# Windows Application and Python Ubuntu Application

Tags: c#, python, bash, tensorflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am developing a C# Windows application and would like to integrate Google's Tensor Flow - a Python Linux application into it.

With Windows 10 being able to run Linux Bash and hence Google's Tensor Flow on the same computer as the C# Windows application runs on I hope it would be easy to flow data between them.

For example:

- Generate variables in the C# Windows application,
- Feed these variables as data inputs into Google's Tensor Flow running on Linux Bash through Windows 10,
- Process this data in Google's Tensor Flow and return the results to the C# Windows application.

I was thinking this might be able to be done via IronPython but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am going to flag this for closure unless you can get more specific.  This is not really the type of question that this site is designed for.  Having said that we had the same problem and learned how to use named pipes to move data between a .Net application and Python.

Comment: This might get you started - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pipe+python+c%23

Comment: You might also check this out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44576/communicate-between-ubuntu-vm-and-windows-host I guess our problem was different because both applications were running on the same OS and same machine

Comment: Also was thinking that if I ran a bash script from Windows 10 containing a Python script within it might work.  The bash script should open bash (Linux) in Windows 10 and then the Python script within the bash script would interact with Google's Tensor Flow.

Comment: Something like as described here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184726/how-to-include-python-script-inside-a-bash-script